# Flutter position Widget between bottom of screen and safe area

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers, flutter-layout

In my app I have a `bottomBar` which is placed at the bottom right above the `SafeArea`:

[image]

The problem is that I would like to have a white `Container` at the bottom (red arrow in image) so that for bigger iPhones (where the bottom of the screen **IS NOT EQUAL** to the `safeArea`) the empty place in the image if filled white.

For phones where the bottom screen **is equal**  to the `safeArea` the *`fillContainerHeight`* should simply be nil/zero.

This is my setup:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              height: 49,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
            Container(
                height: 49,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/bottomBar.png')),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              height: 49,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(color: Colors.white) // -> fill container
    ],
  )
```

Right now the container is not being shown. What is the best way to solve my problem here? I couldn't find anything on this. Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the stack widget like this (the second child (align widget) is positioned above your SafeArea widget):

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: // Your other widgets here
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Another option would be to wrap your SafeArea in a Container and give it a white background while setting the top property to false (= meaning the SafeArea will not be applied to the top):

```
return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: // Your other widgets here
        ),
      ),
    );
```